# Signing Xml from "es-staging.crt" certicate before sending via httpClient to service provider

Tags: java, algorithm, public-key-encryption, private-key, sign

I have got `es-staging.crt` file from service provider whose service I am using.
I need to send signed xml with this `es-staging.crt` certificate. I do not know how to achieve it.

How to solve this in java language?

I have read certificate information by java code, given below.

```
String cerPath = "E:/configDirectory/es-staging.crt";
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(cerPath));
CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(fileInputStream);
publicKey = x509Certificate.getPublicKey();
expiryDate = x509Certificate.getNotAfter();

System.out.println("public key : "+publicKey);
System.out.println("expiryDate : "+expiryDate);

System.out.println("--> Subject: " + x509Certificate.getSubjectDN().getName());

System.out.println("--> Issuer: " + x509Certificate.getIssuerDN().getName());
```

I have only this `es-staging.crt` certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sign a document with an X509 Public Key. You require access to the Private Key.